# Setting up React in combination with NVD3

Tags: d3.js, reactjs, nvd3.js

I am fairly new to React (and front-end work in general). How can I make set up React to work with NVD3?

Currently I am trying to implement the example code of [react-nvd3](https://github.com/NuCivic/react-nvd3), but get the following error thrown by the d3 function d3.transform():

> Unexpected value translate(145, NaN) parsing transform attribute.
>
> g.setAttribute("transform", string);

My code is as follows:

```
var TestData = [{
    key: "Cumulative Return",
    values: [
        {
            "label" : "A" ,
            "value" : -29.765957771107
        } ,
        {
            "label" : "B" ,
            "value" : 0
        } ,
        {
            "label" : "C" ,
            "value" : 32.807804682612
        } ,
        {
            "label" : "D" ,
            "value" : 196.45946739256
        } ,
        {
            "label" : "E" ,
            "value" : 0.19434030906893
        } ,
        {
            "label" : "F" ,
            "value" : -98.079782601442
        } ,
        {
            "label" : "G" ,
            "value" : -13.925743130903
        } ,
        {
            "label" : "H" ,
            "value" : -5.1387322875705
        }
    ]
}];

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
                <NVD3Chart id="chart" type="discreteBarChart" datum={TestData} x="test" y="test"/>
        );
    }
});
 
ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/x2wuko8g/2/ I guess it has to do something with the format of TestData, but can't figure it out.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is your x and y props are misconfigured.

```
<NVD3Chart id="chart" type="discreteBarChart" datum={TestData} x="test" y="test"/>
```

You set x to test and y to test but those fields are not present in your data.

**Try changing x to label and y to value in this way:**

```
<NVD3Chart id="chart" type="discreteBarChart" datum={TestData} x="label" y="value"/>
```

If you pass a string (like in this case) the library will look up in each item of the data for a key with that string.

I hope this help.

Comment: Ha - thought the x and y properties were for the axis labels. Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of work.